# Update the notification counter in mvc 4

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to sync the notification counter on both sides at a time. The attached image will make you understand easily what i need to do on which I am stuck from quite a few days.

Image: 
[image: Sync notifications]

The Right Side of the notification bell is in Layout:

```
 <div class="header-top">
                <h2 style="width:100%">@ViewBag.Heading</h2>
                <a class="info sprite" id="lnkInfo"></a>
                @{
                    if(ViewBag.ShowNotification != null && ViewBag.ShowNotification) {
                        <span class="notifications-icon"><em>@ViewBag.NotificationCount</em></span>
                    }
                }
            </div>
```

The Left Notification Bell is in View.
Code:

```
 <div class="head">
    <span class="notifications-icon"><em>@Model.Announcement.Count</em></span>

    <h3>Notifications</h3>
</div>
```

Jquery Ajax Call to Controller Action:

```
 function UpdateNotification(id) {
        var json = { "AnnouncementID": id };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateNotificationData", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{"AnnouncementID":' + id + '}',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    updatenotificationUI(id);
                }
            }
        })
    }

function updatenotificationUI(id) {
        var $notificaitonContainer = $(".notifications");

        if (id != null) {
            var $li = $notificaitonContainer.find("li[id=" + id + "]");

            if ($li != null) {
                $li.slideUp("slow", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    var legth = $notificaitonContainer.find("#listing li").length;
                    if (legth > 0)
                        $notificaitonContainer.find("em").html(legth);
                    else
                        $notificaitonContainer.find("em").html("");
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            $notificaitonContainer.find("ul").html("");
            $notificaitonContainer.find("em").html("");

        }
    }
```

Home Controller :

```
public ActionResult UpdateNotificationData(string AnnouncementID)
    {
        var announcements = new AnnouncementResponse() { Announcement = new List<Announcement>() };

        if (IsUserAuthenticated)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");

        announcements = _contentManager.Announcement();

        var item = announcements.Announcement.Where(p => p.AnnouncementID == Convert.ToInt32(AnnouncementID)).FirstOrDefault();

        announcements.Announcement.Remove(item);
        ViewBag.NotificationCount = announcements.Announcement.Count;

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

But the Notification Bell in Layout doesnt update with the viewbag value or even when the model is assigned to it.

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: The controller doesn't return a view, it returns JSON.  How are you actually updating the value?  If you're using JavaScript on the page to update it then that JavaScript is going to have to update both of them.  The server-side model binding isn't going to re-bind in the browser.

Comment: I am using jquery ajax call to my controller action. and updating the value.

Comment: Then that code needs to update both values.  You're not *showing* that code, so I can't be more specific.  But it seems like that's what you want to fix.

Comment: let me edit the question and re post that code into it.

Answer (score 0):

You're only updating one of the two notifications.  First you find a containing element:

```
var $notificaitonContainer = $(".notifications");
```

The HTML in the question doesn't have any elements which match this, so I can't be more specific.  But just based on the naming alone it sounds like you're assuming there's only one such container.

Regardless, you then choose exactly one element to update:

```
var $li = $notificaitonContainer.find("li[id=" + id + "]");
```

(This can't be more than one element, since `id` values need to be unique.)

So... On your page you have two "notification" elements.  You're updating *one* of them.  The solution, then, would be to also update the other one.  However you identify that elements in the HTML (jQuery has many options for identifying an element or set of elements), your `updatenotificationUI` function simply needs to update both.